# Stripe custom payment flow isn't showing checkout form in React.js

Tags: reactjs, iframe, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement a Stripe checkout form in my website but nothing is showing up in the iframe that is loaded into the page.
[image: Empty iframe]

I first tried these instructions https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart

[image: stripe docs]

And then went onto the Stripe GitHub and tried use the react examples but still could not get it to work https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-payment/tree/main/payment-element/client/react-cra

Below are the main 2 components used.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import CheckoutForm from './CheckoutForm'

function Payment(props) {
  const { stripePromise } = props;
  const [ clientSecret, setClientSecret ] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/create-payment-intent")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(({clientSecret}) => setClientSecret(clientSecret));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Payment</h1>
      {clientSecret && stripePromise && (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret, }}>
          <CheckoutForm />
        </Elements>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

```
import {
  PaymentElement
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
import {useState} from 'react'
import {useStripe, useElements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

export default function CheckoutForm() {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
      // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
        return_url: `${window.location.origin}/completion`,
      },
    });

    // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
    // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
    // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
    // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
    // redirected to the `return_url`.
    if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
      setMessage(error.message);
    } else {
      setMessage("An unexpected error occured.");
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element" />
      <button disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
        <span id="button-text">
          {isLoading ? <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div> : "Pay now"}
        </span>
      </button>
      {/* Show any error or success messages */}
      {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what is the issue yet, but you can start by debugging around this line:
<Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret, }}>


Try to print out the clientSecret to see if you have a valid value in the form of "pi_xxx_secret_yyy", or define options as a separate struct like Stripe's official Doc: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#add-and-configure-the-elements-provider-to-your-payment-page


Also if you open console, do you see any error?

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issues and this is how i solved it. first check if you are getting the clientsecret from your api request by console.log thre return data
if that is been return

them make the option parameter like this

```
const options={
    clientSecret:'your clientsecret'
   }

 {clientSecret &&  (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
          <CheckoutForm />
        </Elements>
      )}
```